# Groovy grammar shortcut for HashMap (environment variable example)

Tags: groovy, gradle

What would be more groovyish to re-write

```
task envvar << {
    all = System.getenv();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : all.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
task envvar << {
    System.getenv().each { key, value -> println "${key}/${value}" }
}
```

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps